# Как пройтись через map<string, int> благодаря итератору и вектору строк?

Tags: c++, vector, map

Имеется `map<string, int>` и `vector<string>`

Надо пройтись по всем строкам вектора и проверить значения `value` в `map`.

```
void KMPSearch(vector<string> v, string txt)
{
    string pat;
    map<string, int> mp;
    int maxi = -1;
    for(int r = 0; r < v.size(); r++)
    {
        pat = v[r];
        int m =  pat.length();
        int n = txt.length();
        int lps[m];
        int cnt = 0;

        computeLPSArray(pat, m, lps);

        int i = 0; 
        int j = 0;
        while(i < n)
        {
            if(pat[j] == txt[i])
            {
                j++; i++;
            }
            if(j == m)
            {
                cnt++;
                mp[pat]++;
            }
            else if(i < n && pat[j] != txt[i])
            {
                if(j != 0)
                    j = lps[j - 1];
                else
                    i = i + 1;
            }
            if(cnt > maxi) maxi = cnt;
        }
        map<string, int> :: iterator it;
        cout << maxi << endl;
        for(it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
        {
            string str = v[it];
            if(mp[str] == maxi) cout << str << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот так пробовал, не получилось

Comment: Покажите объявления `v` и `mp`

Comment: Обновил код, решаю алгоритм строк, и компилятор ругается

Comment: Почему вы пытаетесь итерировать по *вектору* при помощи *маповского* итератора `map<string, int>::iterator it`? В чем тут идея?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С++ 11:

```
vector<string> v = {"cc", "bb"};
for (auto x : v) {
    if (mp[x] == 3)
        cout << x << endl;
}
```

С итератором полностью:

```
for (std::vector<string>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it){
        if (mp[*it] == 3)
```

А так `string str = v[it];` нельзя, поскольку it - это не индекс (при большой нужде можно вычислить индекс как разность `it` и `it.begin`)